# Trigger toast from another React component

Tags: reactjs, primereact

I'm using PrimeReact toast element.

The **index.js** file:

```
import Dialogs from './components/Dialogs';
import React, { useRef } from 'react';
import { Toast } from 'primereact/toast';

const Index = () => {

    const toast = useRef(null);

    ...

    return (
        <div className="card">
            <Toast ref={toast} />
            <Dialogs delete={delete} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default Status;
```

I want to trigger toast inside **Dialogs.js (Dialogs)** component:

```
import { Toast } from 'primereact/toast';
import React, { useRef } from 'react';

const Dialogs = ({delete}) => {
    const toast = useRef(null);

    return (
        <>
            <Toast ref={toast} />
        </>
    );
}

export default Dialogs;
```

if I remove `<Toast ref={toast} />` from `Dialogs` component I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'show')

How can I use `<Toast ref={toast} />` defined in **index.js** but inside Dialogs component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `ref` from `Index` (`App` in my example) just needs to be accessed as a trigger, simply passing it as a prop would work:

**App.js**

```
import Dialogs from "./Dialogs";
import React, { useRef } from "react";
import { Toast } from "primereact/toast";

const App = () => {
  const toast = useRef(null);

  const onDelete = () => {
    toast.current.show({
      severity: "error",
      summary: "Deleted Message",
      detail: "Some message",
    });
  };

  const onClick = () => {
    toast.current.show({
      severity: "info",
      summary: "Info Message",
      detail: "Some information",
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>trigger 1</button>
      <Toast ref={toast} />
      <Dialogs toast={toast} onDelete={onDelete} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Dialogs.js**

```
import React from "react";

const Dialogs = ({ onDelete, toast }) => {
  const onClick = () =>
    toast.current.show({
      severity: "success",
      summary: "Success Message",
      detail: "Order submitted",
    });
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={onClick}>trigger 2</button>
      <button onClick={onDelete}>trigger delete</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dialogs;
```

Here's a [working sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/primereact-toast-example-inj5it). If you need to move the `<Toast>` element into a sub-component and set the `ref` later on, you can wrap the component receiving the reference using [Forwarding Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).